# Какие технологии использовались при разработке проекта geniroom.com?

Tags: веб-программирование

А точно:

- технологии
- язык программирования
- какое было доп. железо, если оно было использовано,
- какие сервера (в плане отказоустойчивости).

Конечно же, все это примерные данные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Under the Site: geniroom.com](http://underthesite.com/sites/geniroom.com).